# does not show the expected result when use __get() in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
class classname
{
public $attribute;
function __get($name)
{
return 'here:'.$this->$name;
}
function __set ($name, $value)
{
$this->$name = $value;
}
}
$a = new classname();
$a->attribute = 5;
echo $a->attribute;
```

When I run above script, it shows:5

Question:

`echo $a->attribute;` this line of code will invoke `function __get($name)`, right? so why it does not show: `here:5` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic __get and __set and __call are only called if the property properties or methods are undefined or unaccessible from the calling scope, or undefined.

To make this work you will have to remove a public reference to attribute or make it protected or private.

```
class classname
{
  protected $attribute;
  function __get($name)
  {
    return 'here:'.$this->$name;
  }
  function __set ($name, $value)
  {
    $this->$name = $value;
  }
}
$a = new classname();
$a->attribute = 5; //  calling __set
echo $a->attribute; // calling __get
```

Answer (score 2):

You marked the property public, and so the property is accessible from outside of the class.

> __get() is utilized for reading data from **inaccessible properties**.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

If you want to force arbitrary properties to make __get and __set be called, you can stash them in a private map:

```
class classname
{
    private $vars = array();
    function __get($name)
    {
        return 'here:'.$this->vars[$name];
    }
    function __set ($name, $value)
    {
        $this->vars[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here 'attribute ' is public ,so __get() magic method will not be called.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: here to refer to PHP official manual link:http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get